# Exchange: give access to a mailbox, but disallow moving/deleting folders

Tags: exchange, outlook

Using exchange is it possible to give a user access to a mailbox so that they can move and delete mails but not move and delete folders?  A solution that requires a change to every folder in the account is fine as there are only a few dozen and they do not change very often.

What I am trying to avoid is users dragging folders around or deleting them by accident when they are working in a shared support mailbox.

Comment: Possibly.. in a hacky way.  What version of Exchange and Outlook are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

Sorry about that. 
HopelessNoob, thanks for flagging.

PFDavAdmin cannot be used in Exchange 2010Sp1 or later.
For Ex2010 you need ExFolders
You can download it from here
http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Exchange-2010-SP1-ExFolders-e6bfd405

**Installation:**

1. You need to extract it to your Exchange Bin directory c:\program
   files\microsoft\exchange\v14\bin
2. Also, you need to add the registry entries which came in the zip (double-click and add it to
   registry)

**Before you work on a mailbox folder**

a) Open EMC
b) Drill down to 
Recipient Config > Mailboxes
Right click on the mailbox > manage full access permission
and give Full Access Permission to the logged in service account you are using.

**Open ExFolders from \bin**

Connect to GC / Connect to Database folder.
Expand the left tree and drill down to the mailbox.
Select Top of Information Store,
RightClick on the folder you would need to give permission to and search for the username from the list.
Select the user as Contributor, and select appropriate Delete Permissions (Own/All).
Ensure that you do not make them Folder Owner.

Screenshot here
[image: ExFolders Screenshot]

hth

---

PREVIOUS Answer > Wrong.
You can use PFDavAdmin to do this in Exchange 2010 and prior versions.
http://www.msexchange.org/articles/PFDavAdmin-tool-Part1.html

Comment: I'm downvoting this because you don't actually answer the question to say how to do it.  (It's non-trivial.)  And because PFDavAdmin doesn't work on Exchange 2010.  There's a different program that does.  Please edit your answer to correct those issues and provide a useful answer.